# Secure Boot Not Working Anymore (MOK)

Tags: boot

I have issues with Secure Boot.

First installation on Ubuntu, I enrolled MOK key.

Sometime later I needed to clean install Ubuntu again. So I disabled Secure Boot MOK with the command `mokutil --disable-validation`. After a reinstall of Ubuntu I enabled MOK with the command `mokutil --enable-validation`.

Now it won't boot. So I disabled Secure Boot in BIOS. Only that way I can launch Ubuntu.

How can I launch Ubuntu with Secure Boot.
How can I resolve the MOK problem?

Current terminal outputs:

```
$ mokutil -sb-state
  SecureBoot disabled
```

While the `mokutil --list-enrolled` command lists a single key `[key 1] SHA1 Fingerprint...`